# How to mock static method using mockito+powerMock+testNg

Tags: java, spring, mockito, testng, powermock

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@ContextConfiguration({ "/spring-test.xml" })
public class ServiceImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{}
```

What should be the maven configuration and code changes required to write unit test case by mocking static method using mockito+powerMock+testNg.

Tried following steps but doesn't work:

1. @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
2. @PrepareForTest(Static.class)
3. PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
4. Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(param)).thenReturn(value);

Comment: Guys, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Well, you asked for it: Why don't you refactor the static method out? PowerMock helps you solve problems that you shouldn't have if your code wasn't in some way bad. The actual solution is better code, without static method in this context and not tools to work around it. This is why I consider the need to use PowerMock&Co to be actually admitting defeat.

Comment: So, you are suggesting static methods are useless and should never be used, And people should not have come up with powerMock or framework to test static method? In order to discourage practice writing static methods in the code .

Comment: Nope, what I suggest is that I consider it a sign of a code smell to need a tool like PowerMock. Static methods can be useful in various places, but as soon as they make testing harder - that's a code smell. As soon as your static methods hide actual dependencies - that's a code smell.
In other words, what I believe is that there are static methods that are pretty much harmless (even if one could argue if they are good style) and there are static methods that will end up being trouble... and it looks like you have one of the later in your code there.